# android:stretchColumns

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I guess I just havent found a good explanation here.  So can anyone please tell me what `android:stretchColumns` actually does?  I have it in my table and have tried several different values but cannot seem to figure out what it is doing.

Sorry for the dumb question!

Comment: Worksnop, if you need future references, you could visit this blog: http://android-pro.blogspot.com/2010/02/table-layout.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> ```
> A TableLayout can specify certain columns as shrinkable or stretchable
> ```
>
> by calling setColumnShrinkable() or
>   **setColumnStretchable**(). If marked as
>   shrinkable, the column width can be
>   shrunk to fit the table into its
>   parent object. **If marked as
>   stretchable, it can expand in width to
>   fit any extra space. The total width
>   of the table is defined by its parent
>   container.**

Have a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html#setColumnStretchable%28int,%20boolean%29), keep in mind that if your table fits nicely ( no space left to stretch) in the parent object, you would not see any changes no matter what value you put in.